# Save Logging messages when I click hyperlink

Tags: java, jsp, logging, web, hyperlink

I created Dynamic Web Project in Java using eclipse. Also I created SearchForm web file with search textbox and  button in it.  When I search for some keyword I have list of results(hyperlink texts). Also I'm using Tomcat 7.0 web server for local use.

My question is: When I click some of the results(hyperlink text) I want hyperlink text to be saved in logging file.

For example:

```
2014-06-03 09:55:01,002 INFO root:02 - Selected: HYPERLINK TEXT
```

Can you please help or suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the links are internal to your web application, then you have a couple of options. You can log the request in your web server (if using), or in your application you could log the request in a `javax.servlet.Filter`,`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` or whatever other component processes your requests. If the links are external, then you could use javascript to capture the event and notify your application with the details.

Comment: the links are external. Can you please help me with some javascript code for storing logging messages in file when the click event is captured. Thanks

Comment: This site is for helping people with specific problems. Try Googling 'javascript click url' and if you get stuck post a question with what you tried and the problem you encountered.